# Is long distance relationship Haram or halal?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I have a long distance relationship with a Muslim girl.
We usually message each other and meet once every one or two month.
Just talking and eating together nothing else.
I told her that I will not talk to her during Ramadan and will call her after Ramadan.

What I want to know is

Is our relationship permissible?

Although I want to do Nikah with her, I can't afford financially now and Still in school with No work or Income.
What Should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

‏سلام عليكم

you should handle this situation the way of the Quran and sunnah things that start off haraam don’t usually have good ending. Get her parents involved and make sure her wali is there when you talk or meet up. Creating a group chat with her wali can help keep things halal. If she's willing to wait until you're ready to take care of her, go for it the right way. If not, maybe she's not the one for you. sabr is the key. If either you guys do not think you’re going to get married, you should not be talking.

‏الله أعلم